# sqlite query not executing on react native

Tags: sqlite, react-native

I need to fetch data from the table 'pet'.
The database and the table are existing one.When executing this code getting this.state.petname as 'def'.

```
var SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage')
var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name:'test.db',createFromLocation:'~sample.db'})
class Register extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      petname: "abc",
    };
    db.transaction((tx) => {
                  this.setState({petname:"def"});

        tx.executeSql('SELECT petname FROM pet WHERE owner = ?',['Mary'],(tx, results) => {
        this.setState({petname:"klm"});
        var len = results.rows.length;
        if(len > 0){
          var row = results.rows.item(0);
          this.setState({petname:row.petname});
        }
        else{
            this.setState({petname:"hij"});
         }

      });
    });
  }
  ............
        }
```

Comment: `var len = results.row.length` should be `var len = results.rows.length`

Comment: yea thanks ..but i couldn't fix my issue.Still am getting this.state.petname value as 'def'.

Comment: `setState` happens asynchronously. This might be the issue. Use callback like `this.setState({foo: 'bar'}, ()=>/* things should happen after setState */)`

Comment: btw why cant even have this.state.petname value as 'klm'. Is there any problem on executesql statement?

Comment: try doing `console.log(results.rows)` before setting the state and see if you get any results.Debug your code with logs and see what is executing when.

Comment: What i got in console                         Error handler not provided:  {message: "no such table: pet (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT petname FROM pet WHERE owner = ?", code: 0}
sqlite.core.js:572 warning - exception while invoking a callback: {"code":0}

Comment: Here you go.. You don't have the table pet.

Comment: I have the database inside android/app/src/main/assets..and the table does exist with sufficient data.What may be the reason for this?

Comment: Might be because you are giving the wrong db name or file path. I'm not sure.

Comment: db name is correct.Is there any problem in declaration of  'var db'?